# powershell session return empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, office365

We try run below powershell command and get different result in the following environment, please advise what could be the problem we overlook:

```
$Username = 'xxxx@xxx.com'
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'xxxx' -Force
$Livecred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Livecred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
INVOKE-COMMAND –Session $Session –scriptblock {Get-DistributionGroup}
```

**Machine Environment 1**: Windows 7 64bit Powershell 4.0

**Result Environment 1**: OK. Able to return all distribution group

**Machine Environment 2**: Windows 7 Powershell 4.0 64bit running inside IIS using System.Management.Automation.Powershell c# ASP.net
Sample code:

```
 PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
    Collection<PSObject> results;
    Collection<ErrorRecord> errors;
    psExec.AddScript(scriptText);
    results = psExec.Invoke();
    if (results != null && results.Count != 0){
     foreach (PSObject obj in results)
     {
      //this is where it retrieve the info from distribution group
      }
    }
```

**Result Environment 2**: OK. Able to return all distribution group

**Machine Environment 3**: Windows Server 2012 64bit Powershell 4.0

**Result Environment 3**: OK. Able to return all distribution group

**Machine Environment 4**: Windows Server 2012 Powershell 4.0 64bit running inside IIS using System.Management.Automation.Powershell c# ASP.net
Sample code:

```
 PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
    Collection<PSObject> results;
    Collection<ErrorRecord> errors;
    psExec.AddScript(scriptText);
    results = psExec.Invoke();
    if (results != null && results.Count != 0){
     foreach (PSObject obj in results)
     {
      //this is where it retrieve the info from distribution group
      }
    }
```

**Result Environment 4**: Not OK able to return all distribution group, it give this error "

```
Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.\r\nCannot validate argument on parameter \u0027Session\u0027. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.\r\n"
```